# Ansible block keep failing on syntax error

Tags: ansible

i try to download from s3 and when i fail i like to do another task
i read in the doc that i can use : block/rescue
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html

so im doing this which as stand alone task is working fine

```
---

    - name: s3 Handler
      gather_facts: false
      hosts: localhost
      connection: local
      tasks:

        - name: Handle the error
          block:
             - name: Get S3 key   
                module: aws_s3
                bucket: dist
                object: packages/foo.zip11
                dest: /home/foo.zip
                mode: get
                overwrite: different


          rescue:
             - debug:
                 msg: 'I caught an error, can do stuff here to fix it, :-)'
```

but here im getting syntax error :

```
The error appears to have been in '/home/create_s3.yml': line 12, column 19, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

         - name: Get S3 key
            module: aws_s3
                  ^ here
```

Comment: The keys for your block are not properly aligned. Is it due to pasting here? Otherwise that may be the error.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [S3 module from Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_s3_module.html), it looks like you could replace `module: aws_s3` with `aws_s3`.

Also, you want to align the indentation so `aws_s3` is at the same level as `name` since they are in the same lexical scope. YAML tends to be very picky about indentation.

Applying this to your code snippet, we get...

```yaml
---

    - name: s3 Handler
      gather_facts: false
      hosts: localhost
      connection: local
      tasks:

        - name: Handle the error
          block:
             - name: Get S3 key   
               aws_s3:
                 bucket: dist
                 object: packages/foo.zip11
                 dest: /home/foo.zip
                 mode: get
                 overwrite: different


          rescue:
             - debug:
                 msg: 'I caught an error, can do stuff here to fix it, :-)'
```

Comment: what do you mean : the same lexical scope.?